# Pattern and Orderless function

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, core-language

I'm a *Mathematica* beginner.

I am exploring the use of patterns and (only for fun) am trying to implement a permutations function.

My (dirty) code is:

```
permutations[l:{e___}] := 
   Module[{f, p}, 
     SetAttributes[f, {Orderless}];
     p = Table[Pattern @@ {Unique[], _}, {Length @ l}];
     ReplaceList[f[e], f @@ p -> p[[All, 1]]]];

permutations[{a, b, c}]
```

It returns:

```
{{a, b, c}, {a, c, b}, {b, a, c}, {b, c, a}, {c, a, b}, {c, b, a}}
```

Have you got a cleaner solution without use of the `Unique`?

Comment: Your solution is not something I would ever have thought of myself. It's very cunning.

Answer (score 7):

I have used a method similar to your "dirty code" myself and I don't see an apparent alternative as `Pattern` requires a true Symbol for its first parameter.  I will note that your `Unique` Symbols should be made [`Temporary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Temporary.html), or you can generate them with `Module` to add this attribute automatically.  And since you are trying things for fun you could use `Map` in place of `Table`.  Finally you may consider [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html) rather than assigning an attribute, which brings us:

```
permutations[l_List] :=
  With[{p = Pattern @@ {Module[{x}, x], _} & /@ l},
    ReplaceList[l, {OrderlessPatternSequence @@ p} -> p[[All, 1]]]
  ]
```

Which could also be written:

```
permutations[l_List] :=
  With[{p = Module[{x}, x] & /@ l},
    ReplaceList[l, {OrderlessPatternSequence @@ (Pattern[#, _] &) /@ p} -> p]
  ]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your advices (temporary variables and `OrderlessPatternSequence`)

Comment: @Olivier You're welcome.  I note however that you posted a second comment as an answer; you need to register an account to make full use of this site.  You should then use the [contact form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/contact) to request a merge of that new account with your [old one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/32615/olivier).

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I came up with was:

```
Permutations[l]
```

The second thing I came up with was an inductive answer:

```
perms[l_] := 
 Flatten[With[{p = perms[Rest@l]}, 
  Function[{n}, Insert[#, First[l], n] & /@ p] /@ Range[Length[l]]], 
 1]

perms[{a_}] := {{a}}
```

I can't think of a pattern-based one at the moment, but I'm sure there's a clever one.

Comment: thanks for your answer My implementation is not at all efficient, it's only a stylistic exercise to improve my practice of patterns... Your recursive solution is of course more efficient ;-)

Comment: I don't know whether it is more efficient - I'll test it. (`Insert` is highly inefficient, I believe.)

Comment: @Olivier: yours is much faster for an 8-element list. Mine took 0.1135s, yours 0.0798s, the inbuilt 0.03404s.